# Strange redirect behavior

Tags: redirect, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

I would like to know how to preserve a **`UrlRedirect`** in ***ASP.NET MVC-4***:

**For example i have this:**

```
/admin/category/add/81/142
```

**But after i use this:**

```
return RedirectToAction("Add", "Category", new RouteValueDictionary
{
   {"id", siteid.Value},
   {"cid", pid.HasValue ? pid.Value : cid.Value }
});
```

**I get this:**

```
/admin/category/add?id=81&cid=142
```

But i want the original one ***`/admin/category/add/81/142`***

Here is my Routing configuration:

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRouteLowercase(
            "Admin_LogOn",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn" },
            constraints: null
        );

        context.MapRouteLowercase(
            "Admin_Category_List_Add",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{cid}/{pid}",
            defaults:
                new
                {
                    controller = "Category",
                    action = "Create",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    cid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    pid = UrlParameter.Optional
                },
            constraints: null
        );


        context.MapRouteLowercase(
          "Admin_TwoParameters",
          "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{cid}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Manager", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, cid = UrlParameter.Optional },
          constraints: null
      );


        context.MapRouteLowercase(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Manager", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
But i want the original one /admin/category/add/81/142
```

To preserve that format you can do this:

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Add", "Category") + "/" + siteid.Value + "/" + (pid.HasValue ? pid.Value : cid.Value));
```

or if you prefer to concat strings (I prefer the first one):

```
return Redirect(new[] { Url.Action("Add", "Category"), "/", siteid.Value, "/", (pid.HasValue ? pid.Value : cid.Value).ToString()});
```

Comment: Tell me please, can I do it more general behavior, like to implement custom routing or something?

Comment: Not with custom routing, you use it to map the url format you desire to the proper controllers and methods. `Url.Action` is a "general behavior" already as well as passing `routevalues` to it. Only it really will give you the key-value pair (e.g. id=81). But it's the safest you can go, compared to my suggested solution - a fairly good answer to your question. An alternative - you can pass a (dynamic) object to a method that will build the string for you, in addition to what Url.Action gives.